# QGIS Join by location results in NULL fields

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I try to join data by its position. I have one layer with GPX data as points and another layer managing zones as polys. I wanna get the data from the poly where the corresponding point is within and join it to the point's data attribute table.
For that i use **Join Attributes by Location** with the following settings.

[image]

Running this always results in a table that has all features of the point layer and the additional fields from the poly layer but the poly layer attributes are always null. The "joined count" always is 0. Even if i change the geometrict predicate, no result at all.

What I am doing wrong?

Every layer is in UTM and is correctly shown on my maps

Comment: If you try 'Intersect' what happens? It will behave almost the same as 'within' for points.

Comment: Unfortunately its the same result ... does it matter that the poly layer data comes from a WFS Server?

Comment: Its multi polygon layer

Comment: Have you tried storing the WFS data locally and then running the join?

Comment: No i didn't, but i think it has something to do with that ... the attribute tables seems to stop on 20k entries for WFS server. Don't know the internal implementation but i could imagine that it just not "reaches" the dataset that would be interesting to join with my points, because its after the 20000 points somehow (even if they are displayed correctly, but on join they will call wfs again with limit 20k maybe) ... so i think i have to use a BBOX somehow to restrict it to my current map section (?)

Comment: It seems like the dataset getting too big ... limit is on 20000 but i also think it is the wrong way to preload every data even if there is no gps point to connect with. Is it possible to request only the polys data where are actually points in it? I think i have to attach it to the server connection somehow, right?